# python nested loop using loops and files

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have a nested for loop that doesn't seem to be working. The inner loops variable is not updating as the outer loop is executing.

```
for line in file:
    record = line.split(',')
    id = record[0]
    mas_list.append(id)
    for lin in another_file:
        rec = lin.split(',')
        idd = rec[3]
        if idd == id:
        mas_list.append("some data")
        mas_list.append("some data")
```

now this works for an id of 001 but when I get to id 002 the outer loop keeps track of that but for some reason the inner loop and only the first item is appended to the list

Comment: you can use `file.seek(0)` to go back to the start of a file also.

Comment: what I am doing with the double nested loops is scanning a file and another file at the same time then using the id of field I am comparing it with another file to extract certain data but for some reason it's not working. Basically I am emulating a database join

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating the file object with

```
for lin in another_file:
```

After the first iteration of the outer loop, the `another_file` is exhausted. So, the inner loop never executes after the first outer loop iteration.

If you want to do it like this, you need to open the file again like this

```
with open("another.txt") as another_file:
    for lin in another_file:
        ...
```

Even better, you can gather only the necessary information before the outer loop itself and use the preprocessed data like this

```
# Create a set of ids from another file
with open("another.txt") as another_file:
    ids = {lin.split(',')[3] for lin in another_file}

with open("mainfile.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        record_id = line.split(',')[0]
        mas_list.append(record_id)
        # Check if the record_id is in the set of ids from another file
        if record_id in ids:
            mas_list.append("some data")
```

Comment: but the outer loop id is set to 002 on second iteration which should match 002 in the inner loop... right?

Comment: what I am doing with the double nested loops is scanning a file and another file at the same time then using the id of field I am comparing it with another file to extract certain data but for some reason it's not working. Basically I am emulating a database join

Comment: @robertrocha My method does exactly the same. Did you try that?