# Python Nested Loops - continue iterates first loop

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, nested-loops

Brand new to programming but very enjoyable challenge.
Here's a question which I suspect may be caused by a misunderstanding of python loops.
System info: Using notepad++ and IDLE python 3.4.3 on Win 7 32-bit

My solution is to open 1 database, use it to look for a correct master entry from database 2, pulls a index number (task_no), then write a 3rd file identical to the first database, this time with the correct index number.
My problem is that it performs 1st and 2nd loop correctly, then on the 2nd iteration of loop 1, tries to perform a block in loop 2 while iterating through the rows of loop 1, not the task_rows of loop 2.

footnote: Both files are quite large (several MB) so I'm note sure if storing them in memory is a good idea.

This was a relevant question that I found closest to this problem:
[python nested loop using loops and files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589662/python-nested-loop-using-loops-and-files)

What I got out of it was that I tried moving the file opening within the 1st loop, but the problem persists. Something to do with how I'm using CSV reader?

I also have the sinking suspicion that there may be a root cause in problem solving so I am welcome to suggestions for alternative ways to solve the problem.
Thanks in advance!

**The gist:**

```
for row in readerCurrentFile: #LOOP 1
    # iterates through readerCurrentFile to define search variables
    [...]
    for task_row in readerTaskHeader: #LOOP 2
        # searches each row iteratively through readerTaskHeader
        # Match compid
        #if no match, continue <<<- This is where it goes back to 1st loop
        [...]
        # Match task frequency
        #if no match, continue
        [...]
        # once both of the above matches check out, will grab data (task_no from task_row[0]
        task_no = ""
        task_no = task_row[0]
        if task_row:
            break
   [...]
    # writes PM code
    print("Successful write of PM schedule row")
    print(compid + " " + dict_freq_names[str(pmfreqx) + str(pmfreq)] + ": " + pmid + " " + task_no)
```

**The entire code:**

```
import csv
import re
#Writes schedule
csvNewPMSchedule = open('new_pm_schedule.csv', 'a', newline='')
writerNewPMSchedule = csv.writer(csvNewPMSchedule)

# Dictionaries of PM Frequency
def re_compile_dict(d,f):
    for k in d:
        d[k] = re.compile(d[k], flags=f)

dict_month = {60:'Quin',36:'Trien',24:'Bi-An',12:'Annual(?<!Bi-)(?<!Semi-)',6:'Semi-An',3:'Quart',2:'Bi-Month',1:'Month(?<!Bi-)'}
dict_week = {2:'Bi-Week',1:'Week(?<!Bi-)'}
dict_freq_names = {'60Months':'Quintennial','36Months':'Triennial','24Months':'Bi-Annual','12Months':'Annual','6Months':'Semi-Annual','3Months':'Quarterly','2Months':'Bi-Monthly','1Months':'Monthly','2Weeks':'Bi-Weekly','1Weeks':'Weekly'}

re_compile_dict(dict_month,re.IGNORECASE)
re_compile_dict(dict_week, re.IGNORECASE)

# Unique Task Counter
task_num = 0
total_lines = 0

#Error catcher
error_in_row = []

#Blank out all rows
pmid = 0
compid = 0
comp_desc = 0
pmfreqx = 0
pmfreq = 0
pmfreqtype = 0

# PM Schedule Draft (as provided by eMaint)
currentFile = open('pm_schedule.csv', encoding='windows-1252')
readerCurrentFile = csv.reader(currentFile)

# Loop 1
for row in readerCurrentFile:
    if row[0] == "pmid":
        continue
    #defines row items
    pmid = row[0]
    compid = row[1]
    comp_desc = row[2]
    #quantity of pm frequency
    pmfreqx_temp = row[3]
    #unit of pm frequency, choices are: Months, Weeks
    pmfreq = row[4]
    #pmfreqtype is currently only static not sure what other options we have
    pmfreqtype = row[5]
    #pmnextdate is the next scheduled due date from this one. we probably need logic later that closes out any past due date
    pmnextdate = row[6]
    # Task Number This is what we want to change
    # pass
    # We want to change this to task header's task_desc
    sched_task_desc = row[8]
    #last done date
    last_pm_date = row[9]
    #
    #determines frequency search criteria
    #
    try:
        pmfreqx = int(pmfreqx_temp)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
            print("Invalid PM frequency data, Skipping row " + pmid)
            error_in_row.append(pmid)
            continue
    #
    #defines frequency search variable
    #
    freq_search_var = ""
    if pmfreq == "Weeks":
        freq_search_var = dict_week[pmfreqx]
    elif pmfreq == "Months":
        freq_search_var = dict_month[pmfreqx]
    if not freq_search_var:
        print("Error in assigning frequency" + compid + " " + str(pmfreqx) + " " + pmfreq)
        error_in_row.append(pmid)
        continue
        #defines Equipment ID Search Variable
    print(compid + " frequency found: " + str(pmfreqx) + " " + str(pmfreq))
    compid_search_var = re.compile(compid,re.IGNORECASE)
    #
    # Matching function - search taskHeader for data
    #
    #PM Task Header Reference 
    taskHeader = open('taskheader.csv', encoding='windows-1252')
    readerTaskHeader = csv.reader(taskHeader)
    for task_row in readerTaskHeader:
        # task_row[0]: taskHeader pm number
        # task_row[1]: "taskHeader task_desc
        # task_row[2]: taskHeader_task_notes
        #
        # search for compid
        compid_match = ""
        compid_match = compid_search_var.search(task_row[1])
        if not compid_match:
            print(task_row[1] + " does not match ID for " + compid + ", trying next row.") #debug 2
            continue # <<< STOPS ITERATING RIGHT OVER HERE
        print("Found compid " + task_row[1]) # debug line
        #
        freq_match = ""
        freq_match = freq_search_var.search(task_row[1])
        if not freq_match:
            print(task_row[1] + " does not match freq for " + compid + " " + dict_freq_names[str(pmfreqx) + str(pmfreq)] + ", trying next row.") #debug line
            continue
        print("Frequency Match: " + compid + " " + dict_freq_names[str(pmfreqx) + str(pmfreq)]) # freq debug line
        #
        task_no = ""
        print("Assigning Task Number to " + task_row[0])
        task_no = task_row[0]
        if task_row:
            break
    #
    #error check
    #
    if not task_no:
        print("ERROR IN SEARCH " + compid + " " + pmid)
        error_in_row.append(pmid)
        continue
    #
    # Writes Rows
    #
    writerNewPMSchedule.writerow([pmid,compid,comp_desc,pmfreqx,pmfreq,pmfreqtype,pmnextdate,task_no,sched_task_desc,last_pm_date])
    print("Successful write of PM schedule row")
    print(compid + " " + dict_freq_names[str(pmfreqx) + str(pmfreq)] + ": " + pmid + " " + task_no)
    print("==============")
# Error reporting lined out for now
# for row in error_in_row:
#   writerNewPMSchedule.writerow(["Error in row:",str(error_in_row[row])])
#   print("Error in row: " + str(error_in_row[row]))
print("Finished")
```

Comment: To see if I understand this right. When you get to an if statement in the inner/nested loop that has a `continue` statement, it doesn't do what you expect it to do? What it does do is continue with the inner/nested loop. However, I'm not clear what you actually want it to do.

Comment: Hello Dunes thanks for responding. that continue that is marked causes row to iterate, not task_row. hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: i think the last line in the inner loop is causing the problem... Obviously, task_no is being set to a value other than an empty string (which seems to be what you expect) causing the if statement (last statement in inner loop) to execute and break out the inner loop...

Comment: Okay. This has nothing to do with the CSV module, and everything to do with the semantics of `break` and `continue`. These statements only effect the most inner loop they are in. If you need to affect other loops then this is a sign of "code smell" -- code that could be written in a better way. I'll try to answer your question as best I can.

Comment: chromano: that was a debug line to possibly catch it. However, it never reaches that point. =/  
Dunes: the marked continue affects the outer loop, which is unexpected. I am trying to just get the inner loop to reiterate until it finds one that satisfies both if statements.

Comment: Could you provide sample input files that reproduce this problem?

Comment: What's the style guide on sending files on stackoverflow?

Comment: The best approach to posting data is to see if you can excerpt your some small part of your data files and still reproduce the issue. If so, share that! If not, figuring out which parts of the data your code will work on and which it will not may help you solve the issue!

Comment: Blckknght - I'm trying to paste in some data but the SO editor won't let me- keeps claiming that I'm inputting improperly formatted code. Tried putting it in code instead of blockquotes but same thing.